# Multiple SELECTS from different tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, union

I'm having two tables with the following structure:

```
Table t1
||My_id|| ||A1|| ||A2|| ||B1|| ||B2||
```

* neither of the above columns are unique

```
Table t2
||My_id|| ||Info||
```

* *My_id* is unique in *t2*

I would like to do a **single query** that can return the following:

```
||ABUnique|| ||Info||
```

Where:

- *ABUnique* contains all the unique A1, A2, B1 and B2
- Info is the correspondent *Info* from t2 where t1.My_id = t2.My_id

So far i was able to get the *ABUnique* my using this query:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT `A1` AS `ABUnique` FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `A2` FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `B1` FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `B2` FROM `t1`)
ORDER BY `ABUnique`
```

But not sure how i could get the *Info* into this as well.

Please note that the tables have different number of entries.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the tables on `My_id`, you don't need `UNION`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am not 100% positive this will work (UNION queries can be a bit finicky at times, and my brain can't be troubled to remember every place they get indignant).*

If you include `My_id` in the results of each UNIONed SELECT, you should be able to JOIN their results to `t2` with it:

```
SELECT abSubQ.`ABUnique`, t2.Info
FROM
((SELECT DISTINCT `A1` AS `ABUnique`, My_id FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `A2`, My_id FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `B1`, My_id FROM `t1`)
UNION (SELECT `B2`, My_id FROM `t1`)
) AS abSubQ
INNER JOIN t2 USING (My_id)
ORDER BY `ABUnique`
;
```

If this does not work, you should be able to create and use a temporary table to "INSERT INTO tmp_blahblah ... SELECT" the union in one query, and use the temporary table in a followup join query.

Comment: Modified the query a bit to make it work but the result is not what i expected - the number of rows returned is much smaller then the one i get for the ABUnique query. So i guess the INNER JOIN is not working as intended here.

Comment: I would guess that means not all `My_id` values found in `t1` are also found in `t2`. If that is the case, you should be able to change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`; it will give you all of the UNIONed results, and `Info` if there is any.

Comment: Or it could be because as originally posted, my answer didn't alias things as well as it could have.

Comment: Actually, it was correct, had a typo in the query. Thank you very much!